# How does this interface function return true or false?

Tags: kotlin, interface

Here is the interface:

```kotlin
interface SelectionChecker {
    fun isSelected(book: Book): Boolean
}
```

and in main it is called like this:

```kotlin
recyclerviewAdapter.selectionChecker = object : SelectionChecker {
    override fun isSelected(book: Book): Boolean =
        selectionTracker?.isSelected(book) ?: false
}
```

This is just to check if an item on a recyclerview in android has been activated. My understanding is that when selectionTracker is not null, a `book` is passed to `isSelected`. In addition, the elvis operator says that if the left operand is not null, it is returned.
My question is how do you know if `isSelected(book)` is null or not, as the interface only says it returns a boolean.

Comment: Thank you. I got it now. One last question. Suppose `selectionTracker` is not null, `isSelected()` is returned, which is a `Boolean`. what is the value of that Boolean? Is it `true` or `false`?

Comment: How is `selectionTracker` declared? You should go to its implementation and see. Presumably, it returns true when `book` is selected. (duh!)

Comment: `selectionTracker` is just an instance of the `SelectionTracker` interface. And that's all.  Here is the link to the github repo' [link](https://github.com/kgmyshin/recyclerview-selection-sample)

Comment: never mind. I'll ask this question in another post.

Comment: `isSelected` returns a non-nullable Boolean. However, in your code `selectionTracker` itself can be null, that's why the whole `selectionTracker?.isSelected(book)` returns a nullable Boolean.

Comment: never mind. I mistook selection`Tracker` for selection`Checker`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the source code you can change the interface to:

```
fun isSelected(book: Book): Boolean?
```

and implementation:

```
override fun isSelected(book: Book): Boolean? =
                selectionTracker?.isSelected(book)
```

Also if it possible you can check `selectionTracker` on nullability to understand whether `isSelected` is null.

Comment: Thanks. But I am interested in the value returned by `isSelected` now.